# How to use language in subdirectory name? Community Cloud Custom Domains

Tags: lightning-community, custom-domain, community-cloud, customer-community-plus

How can I set up subdirectory into my Community URLs?

Currently my community is setup like this:

- clientname.force.com/communityname/
- If you go to this page, the following is added: /login?ec=302&startURL=%2Fcommunityname%2Fs%2F
  There is only 1 login page which will take the language of browser locale. I already found out you can redirect this by adding login?locale=FR or login?locale=nl.

However I'm investigating how I get this:
 - portal.clientname.be/nl-name/ - pointing to ?locale=nl
 - portal.clientname.be/fr-name/ - pointing to ?locale=fr

I know that with Custom Domains (CNAME) I can transform clientname.force.com/communityname/ into portal.clientname.com

How to do the rest?